# Unable to install pip with easy_install

Tags: python, macos, pip

I'm trying to install `pip` with:

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
```

Getting this error:

```
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

I have checked that python is installed:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

According to multiple threads this should be working correctly, what am I doing wrong?

After downloading `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` and running :

```
python get-pip.py
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/1y/4bcsjv_97t3793jlxscvccb07rjdl6/T/tmpvjuB2G/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/var/folders/1y/4bcsjv_97t3793jlxscvccb07rjdl6/T/tmpvjuB2G/pip.zip/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/var/folders/1y/4bcsjv_97t3793jlxscvccb07rjdl6/T/tmpvjuB2G/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/var/folders/1y/4bcsjv_97t3793jlxscvccb07rjdl6/T/tmpvjuB2G/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/var/folders/1y/4bcsjv_97t3793jlxscvccb07rjdl6/T/tmpvjuB2G/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/var/folders/1y/4bcsjv_97t3793jlxscvccb07rjdl6/T/tmpvjuB2G/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/var/folders/1y/4bcsjv_97t3793jlxscvccb07rjdl6/T/tmpvjuB2G/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/var/folders/1y/4bcsjv_97t3793jlxscvccb07rjdl6/T/tmpvjuB2G/pip.zip/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'
```

Comment: afaik pip comes with python, so you already have it

Comment: what's wrong with `sudo apt-get install python-pip`?

Comment: @Sam no, when I write pip - `command not found: pip`

Comment: @the.salman.a I've tagged macos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not follow the official doc?

> To install pip, securely download get-pip.py. [2](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
>
> Then run the following:

```
$ python get-pip.py
```

from [official doc of pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

and the actual link to [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

if you want to install for a specific python version on your machine
python2.7 or python3.x instead of python.

Comment: try to run the python command with `sudo`, your error is a permission denied error